# XMPPFramework: trying to #import XMPP.h gives a "no such file or directory" error

Tags: ios, import, xmpp, xmppframework

Does anyone know how to set up the XMPPFramework for iphone? 
I can't seem to figure this out despite the wikis, and the wikis look out of date.

My project compiles fine, but once I actually try to reference any of the framework's classes, I get a no such file or directory error when trying to build the project.

I have no idea what is wrong despite using a bare bones project to reduce any sources of error.  I'm using Xcode 4.2

Appreciate any pointers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you DID NOT just drag and drop the XMPPFramework files into your project. Notice in the XMPPFramework wiki is says to copy the files into your project folder, and then add the files into your project. So, if your XCode project is called XMPPTest, there will be an XMPPTest folder wherever you created your project, as in /Users/johndoe/XMPPTest. Taking step 2 for example, you need to press the "option" key and drag the folder titled "CocoaLumberjack" into /Users/johndoe/XMPPTest. THEN you can drag the "CocoaLumberjack" folder inside /Users/johndoe/XMPPTest into your actual XCode project. When you do, you should be sure to check the box "Copy items into destination's group folder (if needed) and select the radio button "Create folder references for any added folders". You should make sure that the checkboxes inside the "Add to targets" box are checked.

Comment: I did this but still the issue persists. All the XMPP files are there in the project still those files are not found :(

Comment: @Lincy did you found the solution?

Answer (score -1):

There is no XMPPH.h file in XMPPFramework. You should include XMPP.h instead